# Devuan RFS. How to automate resolution of internal IP (LAN) addresses

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, devuan

System correctly resolves external hostnames (bbc.co.uk for example) but will not resolve any internal (LAN) ones.

The question here is how to automate LAN lookups without having to modify `hosts` and the like. Boards in question are likely to be installed in networks with completely different DHCP/DNS servers.

The following tells me which server offered DHCP etc. Is there a mechanism to get this address into `resolvf.conf` or something similar?

```
$ sudo grep -R "DHCPOFFER" /var/log/syslog
Jan 17 14:32:14 dev-k1s dhclient[1438]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.1.19 from 192.168.1.1
```

TAIA.

[Edit 1]

Added IP address of router which is both DHCP and DNS server

```
$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

```
$ ping beeb4
PING beeb4 (192.168.1.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from BEEB4 (192.168.1.72): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=10.3 ms
64 bytes from BEEB4 (192.168.1.72): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=2.49 ms
```

[Edit 0]

```
~$ ping dev-k1s
PING dev-k1s (127.0.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dev-k1s (127.0.1.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
```

Attempting to ping another machine on the same network:

```
$ ping beeb4
ping: beeb4: Name or service not known
```

Various configuration details:

```
$ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.19
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.8.4
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/nsswitch.conf

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          dns files
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing DNS service and hostname resolution which are not declared in the DNS server. You can ping dev-k1s because this is the hostname of your own machine where you opened the terminal. The name and IP address list should in the /etc/hosts file. You should  something like this  on dev-k1s server :

```
~# more /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       dev-k1s
```

So the  ping to  dev-k1s is responding with the localhost address ( 127.0.0.1) .

If you want your local server responding to ping command with its hostname you should add the IP adresse and the hostname associated at the bottom of  the /etc/hosts file like this example :

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       dev-k1s
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx beeb4
```

[More info Click Here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_use_the_hosts_file/)

I recommend you to ping its IP address first anyway

Comment: Thank you dubis. I have tried to better phrase my question. See edits above.

Comment: The solution didn't change you've to add the ip address of beeb4 in your hosts file as you don't have local DNS server.